# Converting NSString to nsdate not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate

I am converting date from  NSString to NSDate using following code

```
NSString *dateString = @"julho-29-2012 05:01 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate* dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",dateFromString);
[dateFormatter release];
```

But it not working for me :(

Comment: try removing "ho" in "jul **ho** ". Might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format string doesn't match the date format in the string.

Try:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt"]];
```

Setting the locale should only be needed if your phone is not in Portuguese already.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the formats don't match.

```
"julho-29-2012 05:01 PM"
```

Follows the following format:

```
"MMMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"
```

Basically your date formatter isn't able to understand your string and gives a default value, `nil`.

---

**Edit**

You might need to change the formatters locale since your date strings are not in English but Portuguese.

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt-PT"]];
```

Comment: NSString *dateString = @"julho-29-2012 05:01 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"];
    NSDate* dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateFromString);
    [dateFormatter release];

Answer (score 0):

your date formatter's format does not match ur date in string format.